# GameMaker: How to freeze enemies temporarily?

Tags: game-maker

I tried to set the `Enemy.path_speed=0` and then set an alarm[0]=5, when it gets to `alarm[0]` it simply set `Enemy.path_speed=100`(the default value) again. But it does not work. enemies are frozen forever. How else can I freeze the enemies temporarily when I hit the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path_speed = 0` and `path_speed = 100` is not good idea. As example, objects can have different speed. I use speed factor, like `speed = normal_speed * k` where `k` is 1 for normal speed and 0 for full stop.

Enemy Create event:

```
spd = irandom_range(5, 10) // different speed, just as example
path_start(path0, spd, 1, true)
path_position = random(1)
k = 1
```

Enemy Step event:

```
path_speed = spd * k
```

Controller Space key pressed event:

```
with (o_enemy)
     k = 0

alarm[0] = 3 * room_speed
```

Controller Alarm0 event:

```
with (o_enemy)
     k = 1
```

And finished [gm-project](http://goo.gl/eJLAfA)

Answer (score 0):

You just set alarm. You never decrease it. so your statement is never true and hence the objects do not move.